# MariaDB I/O capacity with innodb_io_capacity parameter

Tags: mariadb, parameter

I use hdparm to test my SSD hard drive I/O benchmark :

```
[root@mail ~]# hdparm -t -T /dev/xvda2

/dev/xvda2:
 Timing cached reads:   12906 MB in  1.99 seconds = 6477.79 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1650 MB in  3.00 seconds =  550.21 MB/sec
```

I saw innodb_io_capacity parameter for MariaDB is :

```
Storage type The innodb_io_capacity value
HDD 200
RAID 10 HDD 1,000
SSD 5,000
Fusion IO 10,000
```

Could some body please tell me which value i should use in this case ?

Comment: I understand where the hdparm numbers come from - where do the other ones come from?

Comment: This is a path of "Transaction commits and logs" in the Mariadb High Performance book

Comment: Don't have that book - can you explain the figures?

Comment: "There are other options that can permit us to change the checkpoint value (writing modifid pages in memory to table fies). By default, the value is 200, but you can change it if you have RAID 10, SSD, or Fusion IO cards. Of course, these values may change a little depending on your hardware. You should consider benchmarking your hardware I/O capacity before setting a value to be sure that it can handle it well."

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you should increase that parameter - what I would advise is that you set up database benchmarking  and vary the parameter in steps of 1000 until you find a sweet spot. There are any number of MySQL benchmarks - sysbench for example. You could try mysqlslap - it's "quick and dirty" but should be good for a first approximation - [1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-measure-mysql-query-performance-with-mysqlslap), [2](http://tosbourn.com/mysqlslap-a-quickstart-guide/), [3](http://blog.juerggutknecht.ch/database-profiling-with-mysqlslap/), [4](http://anothermysqldba.blogspot.ie/2014/05/mysql-benchmark-with-mysqlslap.html), [5](http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/fun-with-mysqlslap) and check out the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlslap.html). I've been messing with this recently so I have the links to hand.